# C code snippets explanation

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to convert following C code snippets to assembly, but the problem is I can't even understand these simple C code. They are written in abnormal way I think. so I just can't transfer to assembly. please help me

```
a = (a >= c);
b = (c < d) || (b > d);
a = (a != d) && (b != c)
```

Comment: These are valid C expressions. Not abnormal. Have you programmed in C before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look if `a>=c` then it return true. So a=1 otherwise a=0.
Now in second case if `c<d`(c is less than d ) or `b>d`(b is greater than d) any one of them is true b=1. If both are false b=0.
If a is not equal to d and b is not equal to c then a=1 otherwise it is false(0).

---

```
       A && B = 1  if A!=0 and B!=0
              = 0  if A=0 or B=0 or (A=0 and B=0)
```

---

```
      A || B = 1 if A!=0 or B!=0
             = 0 if A=0 and B=0
```

---

> Note: `if (A && B)` and A is found to be 0 then B will not be checked. 
>           `if (A || B)` and A is found to be 1 then B will not be checked.

if B is an expression then that will not be executed as per the information stated above. This is called `Short circuit evaluation`.

Answer (score 2):

Statements like `a>=c` return true ( 1 ) or false ( 0 ).

So in your case,  `a=(a>=c);` will assign the value 1 to `a` if `a >= c`, otherwise, it will assign 0 to `a`.

This can also be read as

```
if( a >= c )
  a = 1;
else
  a = 0;
```

Next is `b=(c<d)||(b>d);`. Since we have `||`, if any one of the two conditions return true then b is assigned 1, otherwise it is assigned 0. That is if `( c < d )` or `( b > d )`, `b` will be assigned the value 1, and if both of the conditions return false, then `b` is assigned 0 .

Now this is similar to the if statement

```
if( ( c < d ) || ( b > d ) )
  b = 1;
else
  b = 0;
```

And for `a=(a!=d)&&(b!=c)`, both the conditions have to return true for `a` to get the value 1. That is, both `( a != d )` and `( b != c )` must return true for `a` to be assigned the value 1. If anyone of those two conditions is not satisfied, then `a` is assigned the value 0.

This is equivalent to

```
if ( ( a != d ) && ( b != c ) )
  a = 1;
else
  a = 0;
```

Hope you understand it now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

They are boolean expressions and return a value of 1 when true.

(a >= c) returns 1 if a >= c, and 0 if not.

Also a && b will return 1 if both a and b are non-zero